# NPM - changing package source code

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I recently installed an gallery for react (react-images) and it is great.

However the class attributes that the author put there are not exactly what I need, and there is no css file. Css is generated through `aphrodite` and added as a class do `<figure>`.

The only thing I need is to remove one attribute, so I jumped into the source code, deleted it, and restarted my server. No results. The attributes stayed the same as they were before. So I added a `p` tag with a text in it to see if it will be rendered, and it is not.

My question is - do I have to somehow refresh the package to make it work?
If yes, then how to do it, and if no - what might be causing this problem?

Comment: why not just fork their project, make the changes you need in a way that let you pass in a custom class if you need it, preserving the behaviour it has now if you don't pass in a custom class, and then send that patch as a PR to the original package author, so that they can merge that in and release a new version of their library? Because that way *everbody* benefits from open source =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I would love to do that, but this involves more knowledge of JS that I probably have right now, as I started not so long ago :(

Comment: Best time to learn! But you're not alone: file an issue on their issue tracker first, going "hey I need the following because of ..., would it be possible to make some of this customizable? I'd love to help but I only just started learning JS so I might need some guidance".